# Sharing a browser page to my app and getting the screenshot

Tags: java, android, android-intent, screenshot, thumbnails

I have trouble grabbing some info from an Intent. The intent is generated when a user is browsing the internet with google chrome for example and then clicks the menu button and presses share. After which a list appears of apps that are able to filter the intent.

After receiving the intent, i have dumped the content and this is the output:

```
07-18 12:03:13.825  24548-24548/com.example.expandtest I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@423bdbc0 time:41381656
07-18 12:03:30.935  24548-24548/com.example.expandtest E/Activity﹕ Dumping Intent start
07-18 12:03:30.935  24548-24548/com.example.expandtest E/Activity﹕ [android.intent.extra.SUBJECT=dick swaab - Google Search]
07-18 12:03:30.935  24548-24548/com.example.expandtest E/Activity﹕ [android.intent.extra.TEXT=https://www.google.nl/search?q=dick+swaab&oq=dick+swaab&aqs=chrome..69i57.5033j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8]
07-18 12:03:30.945  24548-24548/com.example.expandtest E/Activity﹕ [share_screenshot_as_stream=content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/1437213810717-617998691.jpg]
07-18 12:03:30.945  24548-24548/com.example.expandtest E/Activity﹕ Dumping Intent end
```

So looking at the content, apparently a screenshot gets taken when you use the share button from a browser. Seeing this made me want to extract the screenshot aswell instead of the URL only.

But when i try to extract the Uri for the image, it gives me null. This line of code to be precise:

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Even though the dumped content of the intent clearly shows there is a screenshot available, I am not able to extract it. The dump also shows that the image URI is a stream, So i guess i should be able to extract it with the line above but I am doing something wrong.

So I have tried different things but the only way that would work is to extraxt the URI portion in the same way that I dump the content in the output, meaning to extract the URI portion of the string manually. But if I could do this using the android way, I think it would look much better.

What i have tried:

OnCreate:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
    }
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
    }
}

dumpIntent(intent);
```

the methods for getting the data:

```
void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handle text");
        //String uRL = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        mArticleURL.setText(sharedText);

       // Uri imageUri = null;


        // i tried using the handleSendImage code here to see if it would work
        try {
            //imageUri = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

            // imageUri is always null
            Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (imageUri != null) {
                //Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "image exists");

                mWebThumbNail.setImageURI(null);
                mWebThumbNail.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "no image available" + t.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handle image");

    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        //Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "image exists");

        mWebThumbNail.setImageURI(null);
        mWebThumbNail.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}

public static void dumpIntent(Intent i) {

    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Dumping Intent start");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key) + "]");
        }
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Dumping Intent end");
    }
}
```

If someone could point out my flaws I would be very happy!

for completeness sake, here is my Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ShareLink"
    android:label="Add to LinkHub" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem should not be in the manifest though as I have googled this quite a bit. Its always possible that I missed something tho.

Comment: 'have trouble grabbing some info from an Intent.'. Well what kind of trouble? And you are talking about a screenshot and a browser but why? Please explain what the user does and what is happening better.

Comment: @greenapps     Thank you for replying! I have edited my question in order to give better explanation.

Comment: `Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);`. Did you try `Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra( "share_screenshot_as_stream");` instead?

Comment: @greenapps     hmmmm, i did not. Let me check if that works.

Comment: @greenapps     good thinking! works like a charm. Thank you kind sir! You can post it as the official answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);.
```

Did you try

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra( "share_screenshot_as_stream");
```

instead?